# UITableView didSelectRowAt can't get my cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a question.
I have a UITableView, and four custom UITableViewCells.
When I scrolled to bottom, and I also can't get my custom UITableViewCell in `didSelectRowAt` function.
Please give me some advice.
Thanks.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if let cell: ChartTableViewCell = customTableview.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)) as? ChartTableViewCell {
        printBBLog("here.") //just When I scrolled to bottom, this don't print.
        let colors = AssetViewController.Color.getAllColors()
        cell.barChartView?.tapIndexWithColor(index: indexPath.row-2, color: colors[indexPath.row-2])
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

`cellForRow(at:)` will return `nil` when the requested cell is not currently visible on the screen.  When your table view scrolls to the bottom, row 0 is most likely not visible.

However, your `if` statement is doing its job; if `cellForRow(at:)` returns `nil` you don't have a cell to update and so you don't need to do anything in that function.

You should set the appearance of the row 0 cell the next time it is dequeued in your `cellForRow(at:)` data source method.

And, as @Bappaditya pointed out, you have a potential bounds violation crash with `indexPath.row-2`

Answer (score 0):

To get cell in your `didSelectRowAt` delegate method should look like,

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! ChartTableViewCell
    let colors = AssetViewController.Color.getAllColors()
    cell.barChartView?.tapIndexWithColor(index: indexPath.row-2, color: colors[indexPath.row-2])
}
```

And to keep the table view at top, you may want to use,

```
scrollToRow(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0), at: .top, animated: true)
```

Comment: As per your question, `When I scrolled to bottom` why you are fetching cell in `didSelectRowAt `?

Comment: There is a check for 'indexPath.row - 2', there is a possibility of crash for row less than 0

Comment: Because I need to get my custom cell barChartView in IndexPath(0.0).

Comment: IMHO, it's better to add a check to avoid the crash

Comment: If I want to set chartView always at the top of tableview how can I do. Now, I set it in IndexPath(0,0).

Comment: In my opinion, you can use `scrollToRow(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0), at: .top, animated: true)` for your case instead of `indexPath.row - 2`, the outcome is same but it won't crash

Comment: But I don't want to scroll to top when I click the other cell.

Comment: Then in that case you should use table view header or section header

Answer (score 0):

[image]

In UITableView dequeueReusableCell- Each UITableViewCell will be reused several times with different data(image).
In your case, When you scrolled to bottom, cell at `IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)` was reused by another cell that is displaying at the botttom, so you can't config this cell.
Try control with data in `cellForRowAtIndexpath`